# Pyspark - get all the count rows of tables in azure synapse workspace and stored that data into a dataframe

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I want to get all rows from the tables that I have in Lake databases and SQL databases and store that data to a dataframe:

[image]

I'm thinking to create a function to get all the tables and after using the DESCRIBE HISTORY to pick up the historic and after applied the SELECT COUNT(*), for example:

```
DESCRIBE HISTORY tables

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables VERSION AS OF XXX
```

Ideally if it is possible to obtain the history it would be great, but it is also ok to get just today's data, and then run the code every day to start having historic.

Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have diffculty writing a single function which will serve for both . The reason being Lake database is a paraquet file and so if you query the paraquat file , that should work . But SQLdatabse are different and so the same logic will not work there .